# Get unique values from index column in MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I know that I can get the unique values of a `DataFrame` by resetting the index but is there a way to avoid this step and get the unique values directly?

Given I have:

```
        C
 A B     
 0 one  3
 1 one  2
 2 two  1
```

I can do:

```
df = df.reset_index()
uniq_b = df.B.unique()
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
```

Is there a way built in pandas to do this?

Comment: i don't understand your example. uniq_b is not being used?

Comment: ah, i think i get it. you only wanted to 'know' the unique values of B. ok.

Comment: If it's possible seth, I think you should consider changing the accepted answer to 8one6.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One way is to use [`index.levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#some-gory-internal-details):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
       C
A B     
0 one  3
1 one  2
2 two  1

In [12]: df.index.levels[1]
Out[12]: Index([one, two], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it has some very odd behavior in a few specific cases.  Have a look at my answer below for a way to avoid those issues.

Comment: This does not work for me. Index does not have attribute levels anymore. Is this a update?

Comment: @eleijonmarck only a multiindex has a levels attribute. Is that your issue ?

Answer (score 44):

Andy Hayden's answer (`index.levels[blah]`) is great for some scenarios, but can lead to odd behavior in others.  My understanding is that Pandas goes to great lengths to "reuse" indices when possible to avoid having the indices of lots of similarly-indexed DataFrames taking up space in memory.  As a result, [I've found the following annoying behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434724/dataframe-index-levels-shows-extra-values-after-paring-down-dataframe/):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['John', 'Josh', 'Alex'], list('abcde')], 
                                 names=['Person', 'Letter'])
large = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(15, 2), 
                     index=idx, 
                     columns=['one', 'two'])
small = large.loc[['Jo'==d[0:2] for d in large.index.get_level_values('Person')]]

print small.index.levels[0]
print large.index.levels[0]
```

Which outputs

```
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
```

rather than the expected

```
Index([u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
```

As one person pointed out on the other thread, one idiom that seems very natural and works properly would be:

```
small.index.get_level_values('Person').unique()
large.index.get_level_values('Person').unique()
```

I hope this helps someone else dodge the super-unexpected behavior that I ran into.

Comment: FWIW, this is the expected behavior if trying to mimic R.  In R the levels of factor variables (which look a lot like indices in pandas) do not change upon subsetting.  One must explicitly reindex to shrink the possible levels.

Comment: @ChrisWarth Thanks for the reminder about this behavior in R, I had completely forgotten! Looks like there's a toy project some weekend in my future :-D

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `unique()` function of index

```
df.index.unique('B')
```

Unlike `levels` this function is documented.