# DataFrame.index.levels shows "extra" values after paring down dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have a large dataframe `large` that has a MultiIndex on the rows.  I pare down this dataframe by selecting only some of the rows and assign the result to `small`.  In particular, `small` has fewer distinct values in the 0th level of its MultiIndex on the rows than `large`.

I then want a list of the distinct values in the 0th level of the MultiIndex on the rows of `small` so I call `small.index.levels[0]`.  The result is strange: it returns the same thing as `large.index.levels[0]` despite the fact that there should be fewer values.

What's going on?

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['John', 'Josh', 'Alex'], list('abcde')], 
                                 names=['Person', 'Letter'])
large = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(15, 2), 
                     index=idx, 
                     columns=['one', 'two'])
small = large.loc[['Jo'==d[0:2] for d in large.index.get_level_values('Person')]]

print small.index.levels[0]
print large.index.levels[0]
```

Output:

```
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
```

Expected output:

```
Index([u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
Index([u'Alex', u'John', u'Josh'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient to do this.

```
In [43]: large[large.index.get_level_values('Person').to_series().str.startswith('Jo').values]
Out[43]: 
                    one       two
Person Letter                    
John   a       1.764052  0.400157
       b       0.978738  2.240893
       c       1.867558 -0.977278
       d       0.950088 -0.151357
       e      -0.103219  0.410599
Josh   a       0.144044  1.454274
       b       0.761038  0.121675
       c       0.443863  0.333674
       d       1.494079 -0.205158
       e       0.313068 -0.854096
```

To answer your question. That is an implementation detail. Use `.get_level_values()` (rather than accessing the internal `.levels`

You can do this if you want.

```
In [13]: small.index.get_level_values('Person').unique()
Out[13]: array(['John', 'Josh'], dtype=object)

In [14]: large.index.get_level_values('Person').unique()
Out[14]: array(['John', 'Josh', 'Alex'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure you've answered my question.  My goal is not to accomplish the filtering from `large` down to `small`.  My `small` above has just the data that I want in it.  What I want is to get a list of the distinct values in the 0th level of the MultiIndex of `small`.  (For example, `large` might have hundreds of names in the `Person` level of its MultiIndex, and so I might not know what I'm going to get when I filter down to just the names that start with `'Jo'`.  But once the filtering is done, I want to see what I got.  How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: I have the same problem in 2023, and agree the proposed solution doesn't "feel" like an efficient fix

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after having the same problem, [posted it as a bug on the pandas issues tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55148), and was told it's expected behaviour as pandas only updates codes when slicing `MultiIndex`, not levels. You can use `MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels()` ([api link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html)) to drop the levels that are no longer in the slice.

So in your example:

```py
small = large.loc[['Jo'==d[0:2] for d in large.index.get_level_values('Person')]]
small.index = small.index.remove_unused_levels()

print(small.index.levels[0])
print(large.index.levels[0])
```

Comment: Note the answer was subsequently edited to update the `print` syntax to python 3.